# Building OpenJDK 8 on Tilera Tile-GX

Tags: java, tilera

I am trying to build OpenJDK 8 on Tilera Tile-GX36. I downloaded JDK from

[http://openjdk.java.net/][1]

Followed procedure for linux, ran ./configure but it gives out error

```
configure: error: unsupported cpu tile
configure exiting with result code 1
```

Kernel and architecture of tile-GX:

```
Linux localhost 3.10.42-MDE-4.3.0.178115 #1 SMP Tue Jun 16 20:46:32 PDT 2015 tilegx tilegx tilegx GNU/Linux
```

Is there any specific procedure to build java jdk on unknown architectures?
One more thing to be noted that Tile-GX has no internet connectivity so all packages need to be uploaded from connected PC and configured and installed locally on Tile-GX.

Thank you.

Comment: [This page on the Tilera site](http://www.tilera.com/products/?ezchip=592&spage=612#) talks about OpenJDK 1.6, so you may have to be content with an older version of Java at this point. Have you tried contacting the Tilera people to see if they have tried porting version 8?

Comment: Nope I did not contact them yet, but I had success porting java versions on ARM and Tegra processor in the past, so I thought I may find something online. Never mind! thanks.